# Can we implement pre-roll video ads

Tags: android, admob, video-ads

Just required the information and your views.

Can we implement pre-roll video ads before streaming a live video in our created android apps like youtube. Does google provide such service.

As i checked in admod, here we can get 3 types of ads - banner, interstitial and rewarded video.

But does it provide pre-roll video ads which i can play in the video player of my app before playing the video.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, there is no API for YouTube ads.

You can build something similar with AdMob though. Just show the ads before playing the video.

Comment: There is only rewarded video ad by admob, and the problem is, this type of ad will play fullscreen, but my purpose is like play the ad in youtube way, inside my video player

Comment: @RanaPratap You can't.

Comment: What about "IMA SDK for Android"??